# Blink not working

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I have written this code to write and receive signals over i2c between two Uno's. I have a master and a slave code, this is working fine. Now I want the led to blink, for this I added the blink without delay example. Unfortunately I can't get it working at all...

```
// Wire Slave Receiver

#include <Wire.h> //include Library
// define Led Pins
#define LED1 3 //Pin 3
#define LED2 4 //Pin 4
#define LED3 5 //Pin 5

int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
const long interval = 500;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(4);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output

  //set Pin modes
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  //intern pulldown
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);

}

void loop()
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  while (1 < Wire.available()) // loop through all but the last
  {

    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c, BIN);     // print the character as Binary


  }
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println(x, BIN); // print the integer as Binary


  if (x == 1) { //turn LED1 on
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    Serial.println("LED1 on");
  }
  if (x == 2) { //blink LED1
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED1, ledState);
    }
  }

  if (x == 3) { //turn LED2 on
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }
  if (x == 4) { //blink LED2
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED2, ledState);
    }
  }
  if (x == 5) { //turn LED3 on
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
  }
  if (x == 6) { //blink LED3
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED3, ledState);
    }
  }
  if (x == 7) { //turn LED1 nad 2 on
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
  }
  if (x == 8) { //Blink LED1 and 2
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  }
  if (x == 9) { //turn LED2 and 3 on
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);

    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
  }

}
```

---

Thanks for your response. I tried to put all the of statements into the loop, but it's still not working. :P I have no idea how to put it into the loop so it works.

```
// Wire Slave Receiver

#include <Wire.h> //include Library
// define Led Pins
#define LED1 3 //Pin 3
#define LED2 4 //Pin 4
#define LED3 5 //Pin 5

int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
const long interval = 500;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(4);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output

  //set Pin modes
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  //intern pulldown
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);

}

void loop()
{
    if (x == 1) { //turn LED1 on
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    Serial.println("LED1 on");
  }
  if (x == 2) { //blink LED1
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED1, ledState);
    }
  }

  if (x == 3) { //turn LED2 on
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }
  if (x == 4) { //blink LED2
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED2, ledState);
    }
  }
  if (x == 5) { //turn LED3 on
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
  }
  if (x == 6) { //blink LED3
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED3, ledState);
    }
  }
  if (x == 7) { //turn LED1 nad 2 on
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
  }
  if (x == 8) { //Blink LED1 and 2
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  }
  if (x == 9) { //turn LED2 and 3 on
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);

    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
  }
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  while (1 < Wire.available()) // loop through all but the last
  {

    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c, BIN);     // print the character as Binary


  }
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println(x, BIN); // print the integer as Binary




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting how the `onReceive` callback works. The `millis()` code like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example relies on the fact, that it is run repeatedly very fast, so that effectively the time is checked regularily very fast.

The `onReceive` callback is only called once every time, that the `Wire` library received an I2C message, from an interrupt service routine. It is not called repeatedly. So the `millis()` code in there, will only be executed once. Since no time has passed (and `millis()` wouldn't increment inside an ISR either way) nothing happens there and the callback exits. After that the code is not executed further times.

You need to put the `millis()` code into the `loop()` function, so that it is executed repeatedly. In fact you can put all the if statements with `x` into the `loop()` function.

---

EDIT:

Your second version of the code should result in compilation errors (which you really should have included into your question). They will say, that `x` is not declared in this scope. You read the I2C data from the buffer in the `onReceive` callback and save it into a newly created variable `x`. Since `x` is declared inside the function, it will cease to exist right after the end of this function. The `loop()` function does not know about `x`. You need to define `x` globally outside of any function at the start of your sketch.

This results in this code:

```
// Wire Slave Receiver

#include <Wire.h> //include Library
// define Led Pins
#define LED1 3 //Pin 3
#define LED2 4 //Pin 4
#define LED3 5 //Pin 5

uint8_t x=0;                    // define x at global scope, so that it is available everywhere
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
const long interval = 500;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(4);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output

  //set Pin modes
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  //intern pulldown
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);

}

void loop()
{
    if (x == 1) { //turn LED1 on
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    Serial.println("LED1 on");
  }
  if (x == 2) { //blink LED1
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED1, ledState);
    }
  }

  if (x == 3) { //turn LED2 on
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }
  if (x == 4) { //blink LED2
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED2, ledState);
    }
  }
  if (x == 5) { //turn LED3 on
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
  }
  if (x == 6) { //blink LED3
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED3, ledState);
    }
  }
  if (x == 7) { //turn LED1 nad 2 on
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
  }
  if (x == 8) { //Blink LED1 and 2
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  }
  if (x == 9) { //turn LED2 and 3 on
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);

    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
  }
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  while (1 < Wire.available()) // loop through all but the last
  {
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c, BIN);     // print the character as Binary
  }
  x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println(x, BIN); // print the integer as Binary
}
```

Note, that I changed the type of `x` to `uint8_t`, an unsigned int of 8 bits. Restricting `x` to 8 bits prevents problems with writing a variable inside an ISR. The Uno has an 8-bit microcontroller, so it handles 8 bits at a time. `int` has 16 bits and is thus handled in two steps. An interrupt can occur at any time, so the ISR might write `x` in the middle of a calculation, which results in a totally garbled value of `x`. Handling a 1 byte/8 bits variable cannot be interrupted (also called "atomic") and prevents this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to put all the of statements into the loop, but it's still not working. :P I have no idea how to put it into the loop so it works.

Comment: @Marvinm You can add your new code to your question by editing it. Then I can check it for errors

Comment: I'am sorry for beeing so pushy, but I really need this code in about one day. I will give you a little credit as well. If you can solve this problem.

Comment: Then add your new code to your question. Then I can help you

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: You wrote, that you tried to put all the if statements in the loop, but it was not working. That means, that you actually have tried it and created a new version of your code, where you've put all the if statements into the loop function. You should add this code to your question by editing it

Comment: There it is. Hope that helps

Comment: @Marvinm I added an extra explanation.

Comment: Also I edited your question, so that both the old and the new code can be seen. That way others have the chance to also get help from this Q&A.

Comment: Thanks soo much, you are a legend, can u leave you mail for PayPal here. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :) Nope, I'm not doing this for money. You can upvote my answer, if you like